# How did Superman know that he was dead?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

In *Justice League* (2017), just after Superman came back to life and knocked down the other Justice League members, he and Batman had this conversation:

> **Superman:** You did this!
>
> **Batman:** I had to.
>
> **Superman:** You won't let me live, you won't let me die.

It shows that Superman somehow knew that he woke up from his death, not a deep sleep. How did he know that?

Comment: Because he'd read the terrible script.

Comment: I think he probably noticed getting stabbed in the chest by Doomsday in BvS...

Comment: @Loki So? Lots of people get stabbed or hit by car and go unconscious. After waking up in hospital, do they think that they were dead?

Comment: Him saying this is supposed to show he has more then two neurons to rub together. He deduced what happened, and doesn't need to explain how.

Comment: Your logic is "people have survived freak accidents therefore he has survived freak accidents"

Comment: @Mithoron How did he deduce that? This is what I am asking..

Comment: Doesn't he see the statue that they put up as a memorial to Superman after he died before he says that? It probably mentioned the fact that he was dead.

Comment: @CaptainMarvel This wasn't a mere car accident... He was actually stabbed in the chest by a being (Doomsday) who was at least as powerful as himself, so he clearly didn't expect to survive it.

Comment: @CaptainMarvel: Of course, Superman didn’t wake up in hospital. He [woke up in a pool of amniotic fluid in a crashed Kryptonian ship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml_0HnIhTkY&t=2m42), then immediately flew up into the air, and landed next to the disembodied head of the Superman statue that was destroyed during the battle that killed him. So, y’know. There were clues.

Comment: Putting all of the above aside, even if you assume he's not smart enough to put the clues together, saying "you won't let me die" isn't *necessarily* the same as saying "you won't let me stay dead." (He knew he was mortally wounded, after all.)

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet Yeah, that can be answer.. Surprisingly, no need to overthink.. Interestingly, everyone else is also overthinking.. :)

Comment: Or he went to krypton afterlife like Floop Floopians do. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## He didn't, necessarily.

As has been pointed out in the comments, there were several clues surrounding his revival that could easily have led him to glean the truth: he woke up in a vat of goo surrounded by other heroes, not in a hospital, and one of the first things he saw was (the head of) a statue of himself.

However, he might not even have pieced it together.  The words "you won't let me die" don't necessarily imply that he was already dead.  He knew that Doomsday had mortally wounded him, and would have expected to die; not being allowed to die isn't the same as not being allowed to remain dead.  For reference, consider this exchange from *The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen*:

> Quatermain: Well, a witch doctor did bless me once. I had saved his village. He said **Africa would never allow me to die.**
>
> Gray: But you're not in Africa now.